# Overvoltage protection for AC relay dilemma

Tags: relay, opto-isolator, triac, coil, over-voltage-protection

I am currently designing a safety-related device that has to open a relay when a certain event occurs. During most of its life, this relay will be closed, and only open if the safety event occurs, power goes out (the device will be installed in the US so unlikely) or the device needs servicing.

I am designing the "2.0" version and some of the circuits I am using have been taken from the previous version of the product.

One of those circuits is a MOC3083 zero crossing opto-isolated TRIAC drivers which drive a Z0103MN TRIAC in order to provide 110VAC to the relay coil, therefore turning this open/close.

The previously mentioned circuit is as follows:

[image]

Where R and Rg are both 330ohm.

From what I have read in the [AN-3004 app note from On-Semi](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/application-notes/an/an-3004.pdf) some sort of protection or damping is required in parallel with the TRIAC in the form of an RC snubber or MOV to avoid voltage spikes which can potentially cause the relay to close back or even destroy the TRIAC.

However, the previous design has already passed certifications and being sold in thousands without any RC snubber or MOV included.

Therefore my dilemma is the following: should I add an overvoltage protection element or shall I just follow the "if it's not broken don't fix it principle"?

In case I do have to place a protection device, will the MOV do the job given the fact that the relay will be most of the time closed? How do I calculate the energy dissipated on the MOV?

Consider that the relay coil has an inductance of 80H and it stays energized for most of its useful life.

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason not to use a 5 or 12VDC relay you can directly control ? You need to consider, it will probably be easier to pass certification if you can demonstrate the previous - same - design already has passed certification and might save you time and money.

Comment: The power supply that powers the electronics does not have enough juice to power the coil of such a relay. Changing the PSU to one that can source more amps will result in higher costs overall. Yes the previous design has already passed certifications, but I am still not convinced if that was correctly designed and I need to add an extra component

Comment: You have relay that needs only about 3mA such as this one:  V23026F1052B201

Comment: Have to agree with the lower voltage option...

Comment: Does the optocoupler draw less than the 3 mA the relay does?

Comment: If for any reason the triac gets damaged, then it will most probably stay in conduction mode. Triacs are not suited to be used as safety switch. Don't know what they were looking at, but they may change the opinion when revisiting.

Comment: Why are triacs not suited to be used as a safety switch? Will a solid state relay do the job? The opto coupler draws around 7mA, the mentioned relay only draws 3mA at a higher coil voltage, my power supply is only 3.3V

Comment: Special techniques have to be used when using semiconductors for safety circuits. These usually involve generating an alternating signal and arranging that loss of this of this signal **always** removes power to the circuit being controlled. Depending on the level of safety involved redundant safety circuits are used. Since SSRs use triacs or transistor switches internally they are not suitable for a safety circuit.

Comment: Here is a good reference to address your issue: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/02/58/36/33/29/ff/44/89/CD00022856.pdf/files/CD00022856.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00022856.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you put a 20mm to 40mm from MT1 to MT2 that protects your triac and driver IC. Another good target is the load itself, basically with the same protection.

MOV's have a soft low voltage clamp and a hard high voltage clamp. For 110VAC to 125 VAC you would use MOV's with a 150 volt rating stamped on them. I like them because they have no effect on power, just voltage spikes due to current surges due to switching off inductive loads. An MOV works best if placed at the point where the surge originates.

For 220VAC to 240VAC use MOV's marked 320 volts. For 277VAC use 420 volts MOV's. With a surge being clamped at the source, very little of it will make it to your Triac Driver.

Sidacs have a very tight clamp voltage but are very expensive.

Comment: What do you mean with 20mm to 40mm?

Comment: Those are diameter values. Sorry if I did not clarify that. I gave you an option on size because you know what level of surge may be generated. The 40mm MOV's are designed to take 15 hits at 20KA and still survive.

Comment: Bear in mind that if an MOV fails, it may fail short circuit. If you're not careful, it may cause the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: This is fine: the coil energy is tiny, and even a small (7mm or SMT chip) MOV will do the job with essentially unlimited lifetime. Mind that its capacitance may resonate with coil inductance, making "off" not as "off" as you had intended.

Answer (score 1):

> I am currently designing a safety-related device that has to open a relay when a certain event occurs. During most of its life, this relay will be closed, and only open if the safety event occurs, power goes out

Something doesn't compute here. If safety is involved, you usually want the device to perform self-tests, refuse to start up if a single fault is detected, and make single faults non-critical.

Now, a requirement of single faults being fail-safe is a very common one, and extends far beyond super-critical applications. When things get critical enough, you want redundancy so that function is maintained *in spite of* failures. Otherwise, you just want all failures to be safe, i.e. not lead to new hazards. It's just good engineering in most cases. A failure may be catastrophic an irreversible, but it should still end up in a safe condition.

As an example, with relay circuits that have to open to maintain safety, you don't want a relay welded shut to prevent the device from turning off when called for.

You'd want to have two relays in series. On power-up, the relays are tested using a suitable built-in test circuit, and only if both individually are measured to open and close as commanded, does the device power up. If any one relay fails closed, the fault is detected, the other relay remains open, and the device has failed in a safe condition.

**If I was asked to design something like it, I would use an off-the-shelf safety module** to monitor a contactor with normally-closed mechanically linked monitoring contact.

The safety module would not energize the contactor if the monitoring contact was open - as would be the case if one of the contactor's power path contacts was welded shut. Thus the contactor needs at least two contacts, so that if one welds, and the coil is not energized, the other one will stay open.

The safety module can accept either a single-circuit or double-circuit control input. For double-circuit input, it'll monitor the agreement between the dry contacts that close that circuit, and reject turn-on if there's disagreement, shorts to either ground or supply, etc.

In other words: you don't want to be designing this. Use off-the-shelf components designed for the job.

Here's how it might look in practice:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmUHDk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

SW1 is the load control switch. When closed, the load contactor is ON. When open, the load contactor is OFF.

If you'd also want an E-Stop switch, a two-circuit mechanically-linked normally-closed E-Stop would go between the terminals marked S11, S21 and S12, S22, respectively.

UM-9A-FA is made by Banner Engineering, but there are of course many such devices that could be used instead. They probably have one that can run from 100-240VAC instead of 24V - just check out their catalog, or a catalog of their competitors.

**Read the materials supplied with any safety components you're using. Don't take me on my word. Safety is in your hands.**